# DataGridView check multiple checkboxes using the ctrl and shift keys

Tags: datagridview

I found the exact same question (below) on another forum. Unfortunately there was no solution given. I'm new to this forum and have submitted 2 other posts but sadly no one has responded to them. Hopefully this one garners more attention. Thanks in advance.

"I have a DataGridView, column 0 is a checkbox. I've enabled multiselect so I can select the rows with Shift and Ctrl but can't get my check boxes to enable and disable correctly. I want to be able to select the rows and then once selected click on column 0 and have all the rows checked or unchecked, but what is happening is I loose my selection when I do this. Currently everything is Read only except for column 0 and I have FullRowSelect enabled."

I've also tried the CellClick event which is my preference.

My code is as follows:

```
        private void dgv_Off_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;
        dgv_On.ClearSelection();
        int colindex = dgv_Off.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        if (dgv_Off.SelectedRows.Count > 1)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvOff in dgv_Off.SelectedRows)
            {
                dgv_Off.Focus();
                if (colindex == 0)
                {
                    bool IsChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(dgvOff.Cells[0].Value);
                    if (IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        dgvOff.Cells[0].Value = false;
                        dgv_Off.ClearSelection();
                        dgv_Off.Update();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dgvOff.Cells[0].Value = true;
                        dgv_Off.ClearSelection();
                        dgv_Off.Update();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dgv_Off.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not following exactly what you mean by… *“I want to be able to select the rows and then once selected click on column 0 and have all the rows checked or unchecked, … “* … ? … How would you determine if the selected rows should be checked or not-checked? I mean if the selected rows have checked and unchecked values selected… then how would you know what value to set ALL the check boxes?

I will assume you want to change the “selected” rows check box values to the “opposite” value it currently has. In other words, with the rows selected we would loop through all the selected check boxes and negate the check box values for only the selected rows. If this is the case then the code below should do this.

I suggest you use the grids `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event. When the clicked column header is column zero (0), then loop through all the selected rows and negate whatever value the check box currently has. Something like below…

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
      if (row.Cells[0].Value != null) {
        row.Cells[0].Value = !(bool)row.Cells[0].Value;
      }
      else {
        row.Cells[0].Value = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the user to select any row(s) they want by using ctrl and or shift keys. Then with them still selected I want to be able to check or uncheck of any selected row and have only the rows selected change the checkbox status to the opposite setting. If checked then uncheck but only the selected rows. btw rows are set to fullrowselect. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok... The code above does just what you describe.